# NSURLConnection in background Thread

Tags: multithreading, background, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

I want to load something (big) asynchronously in a background thread (use with NSOperation).

after many searches I came across two options:
The first is use with:

```
CFRunLoopRun()
```

which explain wonderful in this link :
http://www.russellj.co.uk/blog/2011/07/09/nsurlconnection-in-a-background-thread/

the second is use with:

```
NSPort* port = [NSPort port];
NSRunLoop* rl = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]; // Get the runloop
rl addPort:port forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

which explain good in this link :
http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/

I realy want to use with the first option because is very elegant  and readability. but I'm afraid I do not really understand the differences between the two approaches.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the following built-in method if it suits your needs. It's easy to use and is reliable.

- (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler